# cannot compute conditionated mean

Tags: r, error-handling, mean, tibble

I have this small dataset

```
structure(list(score = c("mine_score", "your_score", "mine_score", 
                            "your_score", "mine_score", "your_score"), points = c(53, 13.25, 
                                                                               17.5, 1.59090909090909, 48.5, 6.92857142857143)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                               -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and when applying this formula:

```
mean(long[long$score == 'mine_score', "points"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

I got this error, but cannot figure out why:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(long[long$score == "mine_score", "points"], na.rm = TRUE) :
  the argument is not numeric or logic: returns NA
```

Could anyone possibly know what this error is due to?
Thanks

Comment: This is only a problem because you are using `tibble` (or `dplyr`). The rules for subsetting a tibble are different than a normal data.frame. If you did `long <- as.data.frame(long)` before this line, things would work as you expect. Do you know what created the tibble in the first place? If you are using `dplyr`, there may be better ways to do this.

Comment: I have use dplyr because actually I had a wide format that I wanted to convert in long, Please just feel free to share your suggestions

Comment: With `dplyr` it's more common to see something like `long %>% filter(score=="mine_score") %>% summarize(mean(points, na.rm=T)) %>% pull(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning a one-column dataframe, which `mean` does not understand; it has to return a vector. You can use `$` to return a vector:

```r
mean(long$points[long$score == 'mine_score'], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 39.66667
```

---

If you really want to stick with your original query, you can use `[[1]]` to return the first column of your dataframe as a vector:

```r
mean(long[long$score == 'mine_score', "points"][[1]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking was accurate when applied to data frames, but you're dealing with a tibble.

```
tibble::is_tibble(long)
# [1] TRUE
```

These guys refuse to turn into a vector as expected, as is the case with data frames:

```
long_df <- as.data.frame(long)

mean(long_df[long_df$score == 'mine_score', "points"], na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 39.66667
```

At least, tibbles are sensitive to `colMeans` in this case.

```
colMeans(long[long$score == 'mine_score', "points"], na.rm=TRUE)
#   points 
# 39.66667
```